# Export to DXF problem

Tags: qgis, error, dxf

I converted the QGIS polygon to QGIS line by geometry tools which originally provided in the vector tools tab.
the result is ok, but when I export it to DXF and open it with the AutoCAD, the lines are somehow hidden or something else that results in some errors.
so I could not use the file...

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: Can you provide example data? Can you give some more details about how you did the export? I am exporting frequently from shape to dxf and haven't met any visibility issue so far.

Comment: I go to Vector tools> Geometry tools > polygon to lines and then choose the input layer and hit the run button. after the layer generated I export it to DXF. problem is when I open the dxf file in CAD, some layers are visible and some are not.

Comment: Please share your exact export settings and tell us what you mean by "somehow hidden".

Comment: I export 6 layers at the same time, 5of the are working properly but one of them NOT. I mentioned 'somehow" because the layer which I have a problem with exists in the layer properties of the cad but it is not visualized [like when the layer is hidden] and when I do hide all other layers and try to select it by "select all" command, it crashed the software... create error and jump out of Autocad and close it automaticly.

Comment: Have you made sure that the layer is not empty? Can you share example data?

Comment: I would check to make sure the lines or features in AutoCAD are not some weird color.  In AutoCAD Control+a to select all and change the color to something else.